# Netsuite : Autoforward the mails to an ID

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I am working on a CRM.
We recieve reply from the leads and customers.

We have sequences(Workflows and scripts) by which we send Emails to our customers or leads. When they reply to the mail I can see the mail in the netsuite as well as the sending mail id recieves them as response.

I want to forward this mails to a particular mail id which is not the sending nor cc or bcc mail id. How can i achieve this? which script needs to be written or any workflow to be created for this.

Thanks In advance

Gladiator

Answer (score 0):

Try build an action on top of the "event" record maybe? Whenever an email is created with said characteristics do X.

Same could be done searching for customer records on a scheduled basis.

You could also try building an email plugin to collect responses.